# Fatal Error Paid Memberships Pro require includes/localization.php

Tags: plugins

I use Paid Memberships Pro for one of my projects. Checking my website this morning gave me a blank screen. After enableing the debug-mode in the wp-config, my browser gave me this message:

```
Warning: require_once(/mnt/webt/b2/02/56747202/htdocs/website/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/includes/localization.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/webt/b2/02/56747202/htdocs/website/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/paid-memberships-pro.php on line 41 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/mnt/webt/b2/02/56747202/htdocs/website/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/includes/localization.php' (include_path='.:/opt/RZphp56/includes') in /mnt/webt/b2/02/56747202/htdocs/website/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/paid-memberships-pro.php on line 41
```

Checking my server logs told me, that this error occured for the first time today at 00:15. Yesterday everything worked fine.

I haven't done anything on the code or the plugin settings. Checking the folder structure I noticed, that there is no inludes-directory (compared to the newest version of the plugin downloaded from wordpress).

Any ideas this problem suddenly appears with no reason?

Can I add the missing files via ftp or do I have to replace the whole plugin-folder with the newest version? What about my settings? Do they get lost when I replace the current plugin with the newest version?

Can I enter my website? Right now, I am not able to enter the back- or front-end (white screen/ error message).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,Brotzka If you replace plugin with newest one the changes that are done in code file are vanish.Just move PMPro to some other place plugin folder refresh your site.

Comment: You can enter into back end after doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I was not sure, if a simple copy & paste would delete/overwrite my plugin-configuration. But everything went fine :)

Comment: You can check such kind of error from error-log file from root directory.